# S3 library delete object in bucket

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, amazon-s3

I'm using this nice library [Codeigniter S3](https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3)

but I'm unable to see my bucket folders deleted.

I have a `bucket called "asd"` and inside this bucket I created many folders , inside these folders I put subfolders and files for example:

```
www.s3.awasom.com/asd/123/thumbs/photo.jpg
www.s3.awasom.com/asd/123/big/photo.jpg
```

now in Codeigniter , I use
 `var_dump($this->s3->deleteObject($bucket = "asd", $url = "www.s3.awasom.com/asd/123/" ));`

the var_dump returns `bool(TRUE)` and no error is returned.

but when I browse the link by browser, for example "www.s3.awasom.com/asd/123/big/photo.jpg" the file is not deleted, so this means the object/folder "123" is not deleted.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that you are able to reference the object correctly via http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getObjectInfo?

Also, you can try make use of urlencode() for the $url bit, just to make certain the object path is sent through correctly as it is making use of a REST call just to be on the safe side

Comment: +1 for you, thanks man for your interest on this issue, at the end i fixed using the main Amazon SDK for PHP so i got no time to test somenthing more on Codeigniter library, if i'll get time i'll try and tell you ;)

Comment: No worries, personally trust the AWS SDK more so that should deal with it at all times then ;)

Comment: I also have the same issue. I put uri='folder/file.zip' also not deleted file

Comment: getObjcetinfo('bucket',$uri) return the file details, after executing $this->s3->deleteObject('bucket',$uri), and get return true.

Comment: I also added CORS configuration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file by using `deleteUri`

```
$this->deleteUri(bucketName,'fol/1540293790_name.jpeg')
```